# How to remove blank between div?

Tags: css

I have a problem with CSS.

```css
.special-banner{
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
}
.special-banner > img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_01_renew.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_02_renew.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_03_renew.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_04_renew.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_05_renew.png"/>
 </div>
 <div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_06_renew.png"/>
 </div>
```

As you can see, there are some **White line**.

I want to remove them.

Also, I have 1 solution.

Using `display: flex`.

It's efficient but I can't use that.

Do you have another solution?

I guess it causes with `display:block`..

[image: my picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you added `display:block` or not, but putting it in the `img` style removes the white line

```css
.special-banner {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.special-banner>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_01_renew.png" />
</div>
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_02_renew.png" />
</div>
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_03_renew.png" />
</div>
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_04_renew.png" />
</div>
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_05_renew.png" />
</div>
<div class="special-banner">
  <img src="http://wanho1108.dothome.co.kr/hmb/web/n_himages/sub/sub_point_use_banner_06_renew.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: It's really simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try applying float:left for .special-banner and .special-banner > img

```
.special-banner,.special-banner > img{
    float: left;
}
```